# Using a random seed in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

DolphinDB contains many functions involving randomness. But to my knowledge there are only two of them, namely, randomForestClassifier and randomForestRegressor, for which I can use a random seed to initialize the random number generator. Those two functions provide an argument called `randomSeed`, and I can get a definite result by using the same `randomSeed`.

But things are different when it comes to other random functions like `rand`, `norm`, `randBeta`, etc. I would like to know if there is a way to set their random seeds so that I can debug easily when designing algorithms using those functions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, random functions like `rand`, `normal`and `randBeta`  are not allowed to specify a seed.